# Proper use of Java Interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I originally created an interface containing all the methods that would be shared between two classes, however, I realized I wanted both classes to have the same methods, but they are going to behave differently.

They will have the same return type, but different parameters. I can't figure out how to implement this, or even if I did figure out how to implement this, I don't know if it would be the proper way to handle the situation

Basically, I have come here looking for the correct architecture approach to my what I am trying to accomplish and I don't know what that would be. I think I have 4 questions for determining code architecture:

1. Is an interface the right approach here, if so why?
2. Is an abstract class the right approach here, if so why?
3. This seems like it would be a common theme with OOP, by that I mean having a function you what to behave differently given a particular class. How should code be designed?
4. Lastly, my first thought was, "Oh, I will just override the method in one of the classes", but that is giving me a huge headache and is not working. I feel like I never have this trouble when trying to override methods. Is overriding a method from an interface more complex?

```
public interface Character {
    public void setAttack();
}

/*the setAttack method here will be set by the programmer. The 3 values 
 passed by the programmer are then stored into an array*/
public class Player implements Character {
  public void setAttack(int x, int y, int z) {

    attackArray[0] = x;
    attackArray[1] = y;
    attackArray[2] = z;
  }
}

/*the setAttack will still serve the same purpose as the setAttack in the 
 player class, however, the values will be auto generated randomly once the 
 setAttack function is called for the NPC instance.*/

/*Another thought I had is passing the function that auto generates the 3 
integer values (numGen()) as a parameter 3 times, however, I'm not sure if 
this is possible. Just a thought*/


public class NPC implements Character {
  public void setAttack(){

      for(int i = 0; i < attackArray.length; i++)
    {
        attackArray[i] = numGen();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *//Why can't I just @Override here?* because of number of arguments...

Comment: You could `over-load` the method `setAttack()`

Comment: Or maybe make it var-args? `setAttack(int.... xyz)`, depends on the usecase.

Comment: If you need help with design you will want to give more information on the classes - their relevant properties and the implementation of the methods.

Comment: @user1803551 I have edited my code to provide more function details. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a conceptual misconception: having the *same* methods means more than implementing methods that have the same **name**.

When you use polymorphism and interfaces in Java, then you are expressing intent. As in: classes implementing some interfaces must provide the corresponding "functionality". In other words: this describes a certain behavior.

Thing is: when the interface has `foo()`, and different classes might want a `foo(X)`, and `foo(Y)` then the real question is: do these methods have more in common than just the name?!

If so, one possible solution would be another layer of abstraction. In your case, like:

```
public interface AttackParameters {
...


public interface Character {  
  public void setAttack(AttackParameters parms);
```

or something alike. The idea is to again replace "specific" details with a generic solution.

Alternatively, you could use a `Map<String, Object>`  argument for your `setAttack()` method. In other words: attack parameters are identified by strings.

That is nice and dynamic, but well, it also sidesteps compile time safety. A slightly better version of the map approach would not use Strings as keys, but some **enum** class.

Comment: Thanks so much for the helpful information.  Would you mind providing a small example for for both the your two suggested alternatives if you have a moment, if not, no worries at all :)

Comment: When an interface or class is **public**, then you can have only one per file. I just put them above each other as example. Not sure if I will have the time today to add more example code.

Comment: No worries. Thanks so much! The fact of you taking time out of your day to reply is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes of course, still pondering on your wise words lol. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It would help to understand that a method is defined by its *signature*, which is its name and its arguments. You can only override methods with the same signature. The return type is irrelevant because it can always be ignored.

If there are 2 methods in a type with the *same name* but *different arguments*, they are said to be *overloaded*.

Overloaded methods are used usually when the input can be represented in different ways, but the method still behaves the same. Here is a usual example of correct usage of overloading:

```
double distanceFromOrigin(double x, double y) {
    return Math.hypot(x, y);
}

double distanceFromOrigin(Point point) {
    return distanceFromOrigin(point.getX(), point.getY());
}
```

Another usage is for convenience methods that take less parameters and are a shortcut to the full method:

```
void setLocation(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

/**
 * A convenience method for setting the location to the origin.
 *
 * @implSpec This call is equivalent to {@code setLocation(0, 0)}.
 */
void setLocation() {
    setLocation(0, 0);
}
```

However, just giving methods the same name if they don't do the same thing is generally unwise as it does not make the intent clear.

In your case, both `Player` and `NPC` have an `int[3]` that is populated by the methods. I would use an `abstract` class that holds the array. Now your choice is at what level to have each method. If both classes can make use of both, have them at the superclass level:

```
public abstract class Character {

    int[] attackArray = new int[3];

    public void setAttack(int x, int y, int z) {
        attackArray[0] = x;
        attackArray[1] = y;
        attackArray[2] = z;
    }

    /**
     * Populates the attack array with random numbers.
     */
    public void setAttack() {
        setAttack(numGen(), numGen(), numGen());
    }
}
```

In this case you have overloaded methods which are both inherited by both `Player` and `NPC`. If each class can only use its own method, have them at the subclass level:

```
public class Player extends Character {

    public void setAttack(int x, int y, int z) {
        attackArray[0] = x;
        attackArray[1] = y;
        attackArray[2] = z;
    }
}

public class NPC extends Character {

    public void setAttack() {
        for(int i = 0; i < attackArray.length; i++) {
            attackArray[i] = numGen();
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you'll want to have the `(int x, int y, int z)` method available to both classes (put it in the superclass), but the no-args one available only to the NPC (put it in its subclass).

What you need to ask yourself is how the methods will be used. Based on that, you would know where to put them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Why won't my either of my classes allow me to method overload the method from my interface?

Comment: @JonathanDeLorenzo You mean override? I explained that in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Nothing is really to be done for method overloading, however, method overriding must meet a certain criteria. Assuming because when method overloading you are creating completely different signatures so you can have the same name all you want with different params and they have no relation.

Comment: @JonathanDeLorenzo See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you've already accepted an answer, but still wanted to give you my solution as well. I'd appreciate it if you were to go through it as well.

In your scenario, we can make use of `varargs`. It reduces a lot of boilerplate code. Now, other answers have stated that you will need to create different methods for `setAttack()` (depending on the number of parameters) or multiple interfaces. But now suppose you have 10 different permutations and combinations of parameters, would you create 10 separate interfaces or 10 different method signatures? Maybe, maybe not.

The same can be achieved as follows using `varargs`. Declare your abstract class :

```
public abstract class Character {
   int[] attackArray = new int[3];
   public abstract void setAttack(int... values); //using varargs
}
```

Now each class can extend this and override it as desired.

```
// Player
public class Player extends Character {
   @Override
   public void setAttack(int... values) {
      attackArray[0] = values[0];
      attackArray[1] = values[1];
      attackArray[2] = values[2];
   }
}

// NPC
public class NPC extends Character {
   @Override
   public void setAttack(int... values) {
      for(int i = 0; i < attackArray.length; i++) {
         attackArray[i] = numGen();
      }
   }
}
```

Thereby, using this approach you have just one abstract method `setAttack()` and different implementations of it and all using just 1 abstract class.

Comment: Dude I'm absolutely going to read this. I really appreciate you taking the time to reply. Seriously, thanks so much!